# Primitive shapes

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I want to justify that whether a half circle can spit into primitive shapes?

for example,  can I split the following object into primitive shapes as shown in that figure? 
also, what are the primitive shapes of object "b"?

[image]

Comment: You can split "b" into a rectangle and two triangles. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

A @Jerry commented,I think you are looking for the following splitting:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Captivating! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. I hope this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: I think it is, indeed!

Comment: @Jery & Babak, thanks

Comment: @sana: You're welcome.